# IBM WMQ binding transport type JNI error

Tags: java-native-interface, ibm-mq, xa

Trying to configure WMQ XA connection factory like

```
<bean id="ibmOetConnectionFactoryXA" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory">
    <property name="transportType" value="0"/>
    <property name="queueManager" value="DISASTER"/>
</bean>
```

i've copied mqjexitstub02.dll, PgmIpLayer.dll and mqjbnd.dll to one of the $PATH directories ($JAVA_HOME/bin), but exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\dev\jdk1.6.0_39\bin\mqjbnd.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1732)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1008)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:273)
```

raised.

here is my cygwin ldd

```
$ ldd ~/dev/jdk1.6.0_39/bin/mqjbnd.dll
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ntdll.dll (0x7c900000)
    kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/kernel32.dll (0x7c800000)
    ??? => ??? (0x1c000000)
```

looks like the problem with ??? => ??? (0x1c000000). Anyone can help with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> i've copied mqjexitstub02.dll, PgmIpLayer.dll and mqjbnd.dll to one of
>   the $PATH directories ($JAVA_HOME/bin), but exception

You can't do that.  To connect in "bindings mode" means that you have a queue manager running on the same server as your application.  Do not EVER copy MQ DLLs (Windows) or shared libraries (Unix/Linux) between servers. It will not work and you will spend hours wasting your time.

If you want to connect in "bindings mode" then install the MQ Server software and create & start a queue manager.

If you are confused by what you are doing then most likely you trying to connect to a queue manager on another server - this called "connecting to a queue manager in client mode".  Therefore, install the MQ Client software and everything will work.

Comment: Hello. Yes you are totally right. And i've performed installation of WMQ manager. I resolved this issue. the problem that i didn't restart my IDE where i run application, therefore $PATH hasn't been updated and java.library.path as well. However thanks for your response